# Batch File - Wait for condition

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that copies text files every morning via windows task scheduler.  The problem I'm running into is that the text files update on a somewhat random schedule (between 6am and 10am).

I would like to have the batch file try to run at 6:15am, and if the text files have not been updated yet, wait and try again every 15 minutes.

I'm using this to identify if the file has been updated for today already:

```
forfiles /m %filename% /d 0 && (
  echo The file was modified today
  REM do whatever else you need to do
) || (
  echo The file has not been modified today
  REM do whatever else you need to do
)
```

Edit - this ended up working:

```
:COPYFILES
XCOPY file.txt

cd C:\Users\cdemundo\Desktop\Inputs

forfiles /m file.txt /d 0 && (
  EXIT
) || (
  TIMEOUT /t 900 /nobreak
  GOTO :COPYFILES
)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the Windows task scheduler for this, in combination with an environment variable: the batch process verifies the environment variable and in case it's not set and the file is present, then the action is done and the environment variable is set. In the task scheduler, you let the task (the batch process) start at 6h00 and have it repeated every 15 minutes, until 10h00. Then you just add a new batch process which unsets the environment variable at 10h00.

Comment: If the files have been modified, the archive attribute will be set.  After the process is done you can then remove the archive attribute from your file. You can use the `TIMEOUT` command to set a timer for 900 seconds and keep looping back to check the archive attribute of the file.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I ended up using a combination of your ideas